# Mapquest language one forward geocoding

Tags: mapquest

Is there any parameter to add language in Mapquest with forward geocoding? Instead of using nominatim.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. There is no language setting for the geocode api. The locale can be set for the maneuver narrative in the directions api, but not in the geocode api.